# How to display elements horizontally in dockedItems and correctly hide tree entries. Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

In the `Ext.tree.Panel` component, in the upper part, I have a search field and two buttons for expansion and hidden recording.
All 3 elements are in `dockedItems`:

```
...
dockedItems: [
                 {
                    xtype:'toolbar',
                    reference: 'tbar',
                    docked: 'top',
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Expand All',                       
                        handler:function()
                        {
                          me.expandAll()
                          me.resumeLayouts(true)                          
                        }   
                    },{
                        text: 'Collapse All',                       
                        handler:function()
                        {
                          me.collapseAll()
                           console.log(me)
                        }
                    }]
                },
                {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                dock: 'top',
                emptyText: 'Search',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
....
```

1. How to make all 3 elements on the same horizontal line?
   Now the search field is shifted down behind the fields for hiding and disclosing records.
2. Is it the same as to make sure that the records are hidden only at the first nested level, so that the records 'Otdel 1' and 'Otdel 2' remain visible?
   Screenshot as it should be [image]

I prepared an example in [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nv2) .

thank

Answer (score 1):

Answering the first item, since you already have a toobar, just put the textfield inside it:

```
dockedItems: [
         {
            xtype:'toolbar',
            reference: 'tbar',
            docked: 'top',
            items: [{
                        text: 'Expand All',
                        handler:function() {
                            me.expandAll()
                            me.resumeLayouts(true)
                        }   
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Collapse All',
                        handler:function()
                        {
                          me.collapseAll()
                          console.log(me)
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        dock: 'top',
                        emptyText: 'Search',
                        enableKeyEvents: true,

                        triggers: {
                            clear: {
                                cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
                                handler: 'onClearTriggerClick',
                                hidden: true,
                                scope: 'this'
                            },
                            search: {
                                cls: 'x-form-search-trigger',
                                weight: 1,
                                handler: 'onSearchTriggerClick',
                                scope: 'this'
                            }
                        }
                   }]
```

In the second item,try this:

```
    {
        text: 'Collapse All',
        handler:function(){

            var node = me.getStore().getRoot();
            node.eachChild(function(child){
                  child.collapse();
            });

        }
   }
```

Comment: The first answer is ok.
On the second question, I need that when I clicked on "Collapse All", All otdels - Otdel 1 - Otdel 2 - would be displayed. Root should be displayed. Added a screenshot to the question